# how to solve the warning "you may need to install module-init-tools" and "depmod"

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

```
 DEPMOD  2.6.32
depmod: WARNING: could not open /lib/modules/2.6.32/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
```

when i do make modules_install first i get warning " you may no need to install module-init-tools" and at last i will get the above warning"

Comment: please help me to solve this problem i am trying to solve from two days but i am not getting

Comment: Did you try to googling? E.g. [this one](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=135851)?

Comment: Thanks for information its helping me

Comment: I try "sudo apt-get dist upgrade" command at that time everything is updated including "module-init-tools" but when i do "module_install" again it gives same warning